# Change Checkout Step Label in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

How i can change checkout steps Label in magento 2?
http://prntscr.com/nr9rrr

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: using custom module or theme ???

Comment: yes in custom theme. i have tried below method but it didn't worked for me. might be there is something which i have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 having onepage 2 step checkout.

1. Shiping
2. Review & Payment

For changing Label for Shipping

copy a file /vendor/magento/module-checkout/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js.
create a new file in app/design/frontend/{vendorname}/{themename}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js

change in function stepNavigator.registerStep 3rd argument shipping to custom label.

`stepNavigator.registerStep(
                        'shipping',
                        '',
                        $t('Custom Label'),
                        this.visible, _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                        10
                    );`

same way we can change for review and payment step in payment.js file.

Comment: there is no such file exists. http://prntscr.com/nrppfs

Comment: check inside /vendor/magento/module-checkout/frontend/web/js/view folder.

Comment: show me all file inside view folder.

Comment: oky sorry, i got this file. for testing i changed the label directly in pub/..., as u said. http://prntscr.com/nrpz1t
but it did not worked.
http://prntscr.com/nrpzdm

Comment: run php bin/magetno cache:clean and cache:flush cmd, then after clear you browser history and check.

Comment: yes worked now. (y)

Comment: what if i want to change these Labels? http://prntscr.com/nrt4uv

Comment: checkout module i18n/en_US.csv  file find and  "Shipping Address", Shipping Address" replace "Shipping Address", "Custom Title"

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this using a mixin.

Create a `requirejs-config.js` file in your design folder e.g. `app/design/frontend/custom/theme/Magento_Checkout/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/view/checkout/shipping-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now create your mixin under the same directory e.g. `app/design/frontend/custom/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/checkout/shipping-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function($, ko, stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        initialize: function() {
            this._super();
            $.each(stepNavigator.steps(), function(index, step) {
                if (step.code === 'shipping') {
                    step.title = 'Your step title';
                }
            });
        }
    };

    return function(target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works very well and doesn't rewrite any files. Thank you